# How to reference a config file out of classpath at runtime (in IDE)

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea, resources

I'm taking over a maven/spring application, where the configuration files are not on the classpath. i.e, the config folder is copied by the maven-assembly-plugin next to the jar, to ease the configuration when the application is deployed.

My problem is that I need these config files to run this app from within my IDE (intelliJ), and of course, Spring is complaining

```
Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

The assembly takes either "application-prod" or "application-test".properties, depending on the maven profile used at packaging time, and copy it as "application.properties" into the /config folder, so next to the jar.

**My question is:** 
What should I do to have this "application.properties" file available in the classpath (ideally depending on the maven profile), when running the application in Intellij, without messing around with the project structure ?

I guess that giving the properties file as a parameter to the launcher could be a solution, but I don't know how.

So here is the simplified project structure:

```
|-- src/
|   |-- main/
|   |   |-- assembly/
|   |   |   |-- bin.xml
|   |   
|   |   |-- config/
|   |   |   |-- images/
|   |   |   |-- application-prod.properties
|   |   |   |-- application-test.properties
|   |   
|   |   |-- java/...
|   |   |   |-- gui/
|   |   |   |   |-- Application.java
|   |   
|   |   |-- resources/
|   |   |   |-- context/
|   |   |   |   |-- context.xml
|   |   
|   |   |   |-- fxml/
|   |   |   |   |-- welcome.fxml
|   |   
|   |   |   |-- gui.properties
|   |   
|-- pom.xml
```

Many thanks.

Comment: are you using spring-boot?

Comment: refer this https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html

Answer (score 0):

In this simple situation without multimodule dependencies it can make the trick.
 You can right click on any directory in your IntelliJ project, select "Mark Directory As", and choose "Source Root" (or resource root as well). That directory folder will change color from yellow to blue (or resource icon will appear); IntelliJ will ensure  that all those directories will be in your CLASSPATH.

Also take a note that you should not try to explicitly add smth to CP var in IDEA. Classpath is configured in the Module Dependencies of your module.